# css div center multi-line text vertically and horizontally with a background image

Tags: css, html, image, center

I have searched Stackoverflow and cannot find a solution that works.

Seems that centring vertically AND horizontally in a div is hard.

I'm using this css:

```
.title {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 400%;
}

.subtitle {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.subnote {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.innie {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 515px;
    background-image: url("bkgrnd3.png");
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: -257px 0 0 -500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timothy Eldon Official</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="eldon.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="innie">
                    <span class="title">
                        Timothy Eldon
                    </span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="subtitle">
                        Author
                    </span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="subnote">
                        (amateur)
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It centres everything on the page relatively, but I cannot get the text centred vertically.

There seems to be lots of ideas, but I've tried several and nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some unnecessary css such as `margin: -257px 0 0 -500px; left:50%;
    top:50%; width: 1000px; height: 515px;` on `.innie` , which is throwing off your center alignment.

I think this, what you are going for.

**UPDATED**

**CSS**

```
.title {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 400%;
}

.subtitle {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.subnote {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:url('https://placeimg.com/600/300/any')no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.innie {
    text-align: center;
}
```

jsFiddle Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/8dphnor5/

Comment: The background img is of a particular size and must be centered.  Your solution puts it across the page - this is NOT desired.

Comment: @Tim I update the css. Hopefully this is what you are going for. It this is the right answer, please vote up or mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim This should center the background regardless of size of the background.

Answer (score 6):

Here is simple [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4quh/).. hope it helps.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: table;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

flex can help you :

```css
.title {
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 400%;
}
.subtitle {
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.subnote {
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 75%;
}
.outer {} .middle {} .innie {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 515px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/515");
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;/* min-height is buggie in IE */
}
body,
.innie {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* now centers things in X,Y axis */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="innie">
      <span class="title">
                        Timothy Eldon
                    </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="subtitle">
                        Author
                    </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="subnote">
                        (amateur)
                    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The solution retains the background image in the correct place, and everything is centered!  Most importantly, the flexibility remains to alter the text.

Comment: For those wondering about IE, it's supported on IE10+ (partially): http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: text-align: center; within .outer {} .middle {} .innie {...} is not needed since flex will do both vertical and horizontal centering.