# Can't center text

Tags: html, css

My problem is that my text won't fully center. How do I fix this? I still want to move it up and down at the center.

```
<center>
    <div class="home-text">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1 class="home-title bounceInUp animated">NAME</h1>

            <h2 class="home-desc bounceInUp animated">HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>

.home-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) regarding the use of center element

Comment: check out my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912619/css-div-center-multi-line-text-vertically-and-horizontally-with-a-background-ima/34912867#34912867

Comment: The `center` element has not been best practices for more than a decade. What book/resource are you working from?

Comment: time to consider using flexbox to easily handle both - horizontal and vertical alignment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left:50%` from `.home-text` and add this CSS:

```
h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make home-text width 100%, display block and text align center.

Remove left position and you can use position relative or set left 0 and right 0.

Comment: Its centerd now but i cant move it up and down with top: 00%;

Comment: If you use position absolite and left 0 and right  0 you can move it up and down with top property. Or just use margin-top property. Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are different ways and best ways to solve this. You chose which one to implement.

Comment: doest work can it be couse i use  "bounceInUp animated".

Comment: I guess you are using an animation plugin then which does a css3 transform. Use !important on top property.

Comment: h1, h2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    !importan;
    margin-top: 50%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

}

Comment: Nope. Thats not correct. You are using !important incorrectly.
top: 50px !important (for example) or margin-top: 30px !important